# String encoding charset issue

Tags: java, character-encoding

I receive a String in ISO-8859-1 encoding but some characters are not decoded correctly...

here is the code I'm using:

```
InputStream plainIs = plainText.getIs();
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;                 
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(plainIs, "iso-8859-1"))) {    
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
}                                       
body = stringBuilder.toString();
log.debug("Plain Text Body: "+body);
```

as an input, I have a sentence like this:

```
L=92objet est donc de proposer un outil simple =E9volutif
```

but the translation is

```
L�objet est donc de proposer un outil simple évolutif
```

the character =E9 is correctly translated in é but the character L=92 is translated like this: L�objet

any idea why I have only a partial conversion ?

Comment: Are you encoding/decoding it as iso-8859

Comment: What character do you expect 92 to be?

Comment: the String I'm receiving is encoded in ISO-8859-1 for sure and I would need to display the string with the right characters, meaning "L'objet est donc de proposer un outil simple évolutif"

Comment: 0x92 isn't a valid [ISO-8889-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) character. Your string is probably Windows-1252, where 0x92 is a curly close single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems 92 is not defined in `ISO-8859-1` (nothing in the 90s are) as you can see on this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) in the chart.  It shows `é` as `E9` which is why it is outputting correctly.  If you are attempting to get `'` as a character, try using `=27` instead of `=92`.

There is also the superset of `ISO-8859-1` with `Windows-1252` found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which does have `92` defined in the second version:

> The second version, used in Microsoft Windows 2.0, positions D7, F7, 91, and 92 had been defined.

Comment: yes I've seen that there is no =92 in ISO-8859-1 but this is a string retrieved from a MimeMessage (coming from outlook) where the part is clearly mentioned as ISO-8859-1....I will try with Windows-1252 then

Comment: that's perfect, by using Windows-1252 my conversion is complete !